# How to reduce the number of fields requested during registration? | OpenCart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

Is it possible to adjust / remove entry fields on registration page?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin panel go to Customer > Custom Field

Here you can add any custom field you want. Just check Required before saving new field, and enable it. After that you will see it in your registration page.

### Removing unnecessary field, like **Fax**

Open *catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl*

Find following

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-fax"><?php echo $entry_fax; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_fax; ?>" id="input-fax" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace it with following (using same `name="fax"` as above)

```
<input type="hidden" name="fax" value="" />
```

---

### Removing necessary field, like **Address**

Do everything from the previous chapter

Open *catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl*

Find following

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-1"><?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_1; ?>" id="input-address-1" class="form-control" />
    <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace it with following (using same `name="fax"` as above)

```
<input type="hidden" name="address_1" value="" />
```

Now open *catalog/controller/account/register.php*

Find `private function validate() {`, Inside of this function we can see all validations.

Look for

```
if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) < 3) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) > 128)) {
  $this->error['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
}
```

and remove (or comment) it.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

This is the list of fields that i want to remove:
Fax,
(If this data can be added in the future in the user settings:)
Company,
Address 1,
Address 2,
City,
Post Code,
Country,
Region / State

Comment: Updated the answer with instruction. Look please.